# How do I swap " and @ in OSX using my Microsoft Keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard

How do I swap " and @ on my microsoft keyboard?  I'm on OSX.

I have KeyRemap4MacBook installed and selecting the option to swap the keys has no effect.

I have a UK Microsoft Ergonomic Desktop 7000, and am using the latest version of KeyRemap4MacBook on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the only reason for the [Microsoft drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-gb/d/natural-wireless-ergonomic-keyboard-7000), as installing them resolved my issues.

Comment: The problems with this driver include very slow mouse movement and broken back forward buttons on the mouse.  I think these might be remediable, and if not will be removing the drivers and living with the swapped " and @.

Comment: Removed the drivers. All problems solved, including the "/@ issues present before the drivers were installed :/.